# correlation id is missing in the Log

Tags: error, logging, uls

I have a handful of correlation id that I need to see in the log what happened this morning when a co-worker checkout the aspx file so he can modify something. upon checkout the whole portal became inaccessible and start giving "an unexpected error has occurred" which came with correlation ID. (see print shot).

[image]

I went through the log back and forth and not finding anything that matches those correlation ID. Could it be I need to turn on more logging via central admin diagnostic area? Please suggest.

I even open the Windows explorer search on sp server where the log is and still could not find it that way.

Comment: I Have Same Error and the Error is this After getting Correlational information ........... Failed to determine the setup path of the list schema for feature {22A9EF51-737B-4FF2-9346-694633FE4416}, list template 850. db5cadbe-70de-4316-8029-57d353f5f896 Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://address/_layouts/listform.aspx?ListId=%7B7aa34ed7%2Df640%2D460a%2D92bb%2D8af5e30fcfef%7D&PageType=0)). Execution Time=830.7980db5cadbe-70de-4316-8029-57d353f5f896 Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://address/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx))
Name=Request (GET:http://addres/Pages/Forms/AllItems.asp

Answer (score 2):

Maria , a common mistake while finding corelation ids is the way it is copied from the browser it generally comes with an extra space at the end. So when we search this using notepad or any other log reader using Ctrl + F it does not come up. Can you confirm this and let us know if the id is copied without spaces.

It suggested you copy the corelation id to notepad first and then copy the required text and then do a search on ULS.

--

Now , if you did copy the corelation id without that extra space, please ensure that you have sorted the ULS log files correctly according to the last modified date in the windows explorer. And then make a search on the sorted ULS files based on the time range.

A suggested way of exploring the ULS would be using the tool [ULS Viewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3308) , which can take inputs from multiple ULS log files and sort based on various columns like exception type, coorelation id ,etc.

--

Thirdly, from the nature of the problem that you posted it looks like checkout of a page causing this issue can have the  scope of the root cause to the following :-

1. At any time there must be a masterpage or page layout not at approved or published state for the site where the page is located. This can cause a permission specific errors for the users when they try to access the site or this page. Please check that.
2. Ensure that there are no site quota locks that are reached while this file has been checkout.
3. Validate everything related to the health of the publishing infrastructure of sharepoint at the farm, web application and the site level.

All of the above are just pointers and not exact solution. If you can share the uls dump and corelation id messages we can assist you further.

Thanks.

Comment: I did all that you mentioned in the first and second step (no space, using uls log, looking at the correct date/time stamped log file, etc.). I am going to concentrate on 3rd list of items you mentioned and see that's the case.

Comment: In addition to my answer , please try this powershell command.
Get-SPLogEvent | ?{$_.Correlation -eq "yourcorelationidhere"} | ft Category, Message -Autosize

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few posts that can help you with the Correlation IDs -

- [Easily determining the exact error by using Correlation ID in SharePoint 2010](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/242586/Easily-Determining-what-is-the-exact-Error-by-usin#)
- [SharePoint 2010 Correlation ID in error messages: what it is and how to use it](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=353)
- [Working with SharePoint 2010 Correlation ID in PowerShell and code](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Working-with-SharePoint-2010-Correlation-ID-in-PowerShell-and-code.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If tracing is enabled, it should be there in trace logs.
Apart from Correlation ID there are other columns in the logs which you can use to find a clue, Time stamp for example. Check the section **3. Trace(ULS) Logs** for detailed information here:

[Troubleshooting SharePoint 2010 : Tools & Techniques](http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/05/25/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2010-tools-techniques/)

Comment: Yeap, Looked at the time frame when the error occurred. Trust me I exhausted all the possibilities before posting it here.

Comment: Try to enable debugging in web.config as mentioned in the article. You will see exact error on the page itself

Comment: cool. I will enable the debugging.

Answer (score 0):

In this post you can find a detailed explanation on how to find the real error message:

[4 Steps to Get the Real Error Message from SharePoint 2013 Log Files](https://mariagraziamerlo.wordpress.com/2016/05/31/4-steps-to-get-the-real-error-message-from-sharepoint-2013-log-files/?iframe=true&preview=true)

Maria Grazia Merlo

[www.mariagraziamerlo.com](http://www.mariagraziamerlo.com)