# Unexpected error when submitting forms using internet Explorer in citrix

Tags: sharepoint-designer, error, form, internet-explorer, browser-compatibility

Whenever users try to submit sharepoint 2010 forms using Internet Explorer within the Citrix environment, the below error message is being shown. But the form works perfectly fine outside of Citrix and Chrome browser in all environment (within citrix and out of citrix). The Forms are designed using sharepoint designer using out of the box features. It would be great if someone point me on the right direction to resolve this issue. [image]

Comment: Please check de log looking for the correlation id and paste here the detailed error.

Comment: It is very strange that the correlation ID related to the IE browser within Citrix is not being logged in ULS.

Comment: Are you sure? I never saw a case of a correlation id that does not appear in the log. Are you sure you verified the log file of the correct time?

Comment: Yes, I did checked it. When the error appear out side of Citrix, the logs are registered. But when the error happening from within Citrix, there is no any logs relating to the correlation ID.

Comment: Check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37469/correlation-id-is-missing-in-the-log